# How to set passord field value by url get variable in php or jquery

Tags: php

I am able to set username field value but not able to setting password field value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `<input type="password" value="value" />` works in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp . Use `type="password"` instead of `type="input"`

Comment: I know how get variable works.And concept of password type field.My problem is I am login in my one site and on click of link I want to go to other site and now on second site I want to fill login and password

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a input field:

```
<input type="password" name="ooxx" />
```

and using jQuery, you can set its value at run-time:

```
// 333 is the new value
jQuery("input[type='password']").val(333)
```

see the live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/AeJjy/

also, you are able to use the method below the get the value from url.

```
/**
 * Usage:  given :  http://some.site.com?para1=hi 
 * para1 = params("para1")     => para1 = "hi"
 * @param {Object} name
 */
function params(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return ""; 
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Comment: @SonelalSingh could you please open the firebug when debugging and see what error it is?